# Find max and min value on a dataframe, ignoring NAs

Tags: r, max, min, na, operation

I need to find the max and min value in a dataframe "df" like this:

```
col1  col2  col3 
 7      4    5
 2      NA   6
 3      2    4
 NA     NA   1
```

The result should be: min = 1 and max = 7.
I have used this function:

```
min <- min(df, na.rm=TRUE)
max <- max(df, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

So I have converted all the values as.numeric in this way:

```
df <- as.numeric(as.character(df))
```

but it introduces NAs by coercion and now the results are:
min = -Inf and max=Inf

How can I operate on the df ignoring NAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the columns are not `numeric`, convert it with `type.convert`

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Or use a force conversion with `matrix` route

```
df[] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df))
```

Or with `lapply`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

With `R 4.1.0` we can also do

```
sapply(df, \(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) |> 
   range(na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1 7
```

---

Once the columns are `numeric`, the functions work as expected

```
min(df, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1
max(df, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 7
```

Note that `as.character/as.numeric` requires a `vector` input and not a `data.frame`

Answer (score 3):

We could use `minMax` function from `dataMaid` package (handles NA's)

```
library(dataMaid)

minMax(df, maxDecimals = 2)
```

Output:

```
Min. and max.: 2; 7
```

data:

```
df <- tribble(
~col1,  ~col2,  ~col3, 
7,      4,    5,
2,      NA,   6,
3,      2,    4,
NA,     NA,  1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
> range(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(df))))
[1] 1 7
```

---

If it is `factor` class, you should use (thank @akrun's comment)

```
as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df)))
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. Added your comments to the answer.